# Are there any downsides to making an application fully AJAX-ed?

Tags: ajax, architecture

I'm working on administrative application.

I was thinking about making it fully AJAX-ed. Basically, there would be only one URL, and everything would be loaded via AJAX.

Are there any downsides to this approach? Will I miss full page reloads for any reason?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

- Users with javascript disabled can't use it
- Cannot bookmark a particular page
- search engine's may find it difficult to index your site

However, there are ways to mitigate/eliminate these disadvantages, eg. graceful degradation, support for browser's history API (pushState etc.)

My preferred approach is to build a site without javascript, then add javascript support, so that links will use javascript to reload part of the page, then use pushState and co. to change the history so that the browser back button & bookmarks work again.

Another advantage of building AJAX on top of an HTML & server side only website is that the website works already, so you can gradually add AJAX, and the website continues to work even if you have not completely programmed all AJAX functionality.

---

If you are using the Ruby on Rails framework, you can try using my gem https://github.com/ronalchn/ajax_pagination. It helps you build AJAX support with graceful degradation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer. Point 3 doesn't worry me, as site won't be public anyway. Basically my only reason for considering 100% AJAX approach is wanting to give users a dektop like experience, smooth workflow without page reloads. In your experience, can this be offset by simply making a fast app and hosting it on powerful server?

Comment: Latency to the server could be a big factor (whether it is in the same region or on the other side of the world). If load time is less than 0.1 secs, it shouldn't matter. Also note that adding AJAX doesn't necessarily eliminate latency (since you may still be sending an AJAX request & getting AJAX response). You can eliminate latency sometimes by predictive pre-loading of resources. The other possible advantage of AJAX is automatically refreshing parts of the page (eg. for notifications or inbox counts)